# Match multi line copy to top indentation on Neovim

Tags: neovim

I want to match the top indentation when copying.
Can I paste the copied content based on the indentation of top?

Souce file

```
call plug#begin('~/.config/nvim/plugged')
  Plug 'nvim-lua/plenary.nvim'
  Plug 'nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim', { 'tag': '0.1.0' }
call plug#end()
```

Copy contents

```
Plug '.../...'
Plug '.../...'
```

What I want to do

```
call plug#begin('~/.config/nvim/plugged')
  Plug 'nvim-lua/plenary.nvim'
  Plug 'nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim', { 'tag': '0.1.0' }
  | <- cursor
  Plug '.../...'
　　　　Plug '.../...'
call plug#end()
```

Actual

```
call plug#begin('~/.config/nvim/plugged')
  Plug 'nvim-lua/plenary.nvim'
  Plug 'nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim', { 'tag': '0.1.0' }
  | <- cursor
  Plug '.../...'
Plug '.../...' <- need to match the indentation of copying top.
call plug#end()
```

:set paste

```
call plug#begin('~/.config/nvim/plugged')
  Plug 'nvim-lua/plenary.nvim'
  Plug 'nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim', { 'tag': '0.1.0' }
  | <- cursor
Plug '.../...'
Plug '.../...'
call plug#end()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is to automatically re-indent pasted text, you can do it with these remappings:

```
nnoremap p p=']^
nnoremap P P='[^
```

What `p=']^` does:

- `p` - paste as expected
- `=']` - reindent to the end of pasted text
- `^` - go to first non blank character in line (as normal paste does)

And with `P` it's the same actions but backwards - because it pastes before the cursor.